# How to split a "one-line text", based on pattern?

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

I have a 1 line file ,contains non graphic characters and I want to split it based on a pattern.
My pattern is  `\[0-9][0-9][0-9]`; how can I do it?
For example, I want to split this line:

```
\001abd \002pqr \003xyz
```

to:

```
\001abd 
\002pqr 
\003xyz
```

I'm using /bin/sh as default shell.

Another example input:

```
CHANGE^\039^OE@ MORE^\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
```

Desired output:

```
CHANGE^
\039^OE@ MORE^
\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^
\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
```

The size of a one line file is 80KB and I'm using GNU sed version 4.2.1 and the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: is that your real data because that is easily split by spaces?

Comment: your example output does not represent your input split according to your pattern.

Comment: CHANGE^\039^OE@ MORE^\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020

Comment: @cas its part of real data

Comment: It would probably be informative to see the first ten lines or so of output from `od -c` run on a file with the second sample output (the all shouting one in the comments).  For example: `od -c file | sed 10q`.  Add that to your question so you can format it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an *exact* sample of the input and an *exact* sample of the output without any semplifications, with the ambiguity introduced by the sample input / output in the question and what you later posted in the comment it's impossible to extabilish what you want exactly.

Comment: alwaystudent, I decided to report my reply on your comment on my answer here, since my answer is now deleted. The Perl example which you said didn't work (`perl -F'/(?=\\)/' -lane '$,="\n";print(@F)' in`) works perfectly on the example later edited into the answer by Jonathan Leffler, who I don't blame at all for having at least tried to understand what your goal was. Next time please add an *exact* sample input and an *exact* sample output, like you were asked.

Comment: But mostly when you use SE sites *you give anyone a chance and post a sample of your input file on your question*, and *you don't mail single users your real input file*. -1. (let me clarify that this is nothing against Jonathan Leffler, who was kind enough to help you and who clearly put a great effort into writing his answer).

Comment: Chopping up such lines I'd do with Perl. But there are certainly alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an initial problem statement, and various solutions were proposed.  It turned out that those did not work because the actual data did not match the description.

#### Workable Answer

> My pattern is: `FS[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, (FS is 'field separator'); how use that in the `sed` script?

With Bash and BSD `sed`, you can use this (which is closely based on what [John1024](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53604/john1024) [proposed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235176/) and uses the BSD and Mac OS X [`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) notation `-E` to enable extended regular expressions):

```
sed -E $'s/(.)(\x1C[[:digit:]]{3})/\\1\\\n\\2/g' file1
```

The `$'…'` notation is Bash's [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism. The FS has byte value 28, hex 0x1C or octal 038.  The doubled backslashes represent a backslash seen by `sed`; the `\n` preceded by `\\` satisfies the `sed` manual which says (in the `s///` section):

> A line can be split by substituting a newline character into it. To specify a newline character in the replacement string, precede it with a backslash.

Check on what works with GNU `sed`.

I also observe that FS is sometimes coded as <kbd>Control-Backslash</kbd> (because <kbd>Control-A</kbd> has code 1, but <kbd>A</kbd> has code 65 = 64 + 1; backslash <kbd>\</kbd> has code 92 = 64 + 28); this probably accounts for [alwaystudent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/121348/alwaystudent)'s confusion in the question.

Note that GNU [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) uses `-r` to do what BSD does with `-E`; POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't recognize either notation.

#### Investigational Background

I've been sent the file by email, and if what I got is accurate, then we need a different characterization of what's required.

Word count output:

```
$ wc file1
       1    8804   80106 file1
$
```

Here's the output from a hex dump:

```
$ odx file1 | sed 20q
0x0000: 33 1C 1C 1C 31 31 1C 30 30 31 0E 32 30 31 1C 30   3...11.001.201.0
0x0010: 30 32 0E 32 30 31 1C 30 30 33 0E 32 30 33 1C 30   02.201.003.203.0
0x0020: 30 34 24 20 1C 30 30 35 0E 30 30 32 1C 30 30 36   04$ .005.002.006
0x0030: 0E 30 30 32 1C 30 31 31 0C 1B 28 32 0F 45 40 20   .002.011..(2.E@ 
0x0040: 20 20 59 4F 55 52 20 43 41 52 44 20 49 53 20 4E     YOUR CARD IS N
0x0050: 4F 54 20 20 53 45 52 56 49 43 45 44 0F 46 40 20   OT  SERVICED.F@ 
0x0060: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 42 59 20 20 54 48 49            BY  THI
0x0070: 53 20 41 54 4D 20 0F 47 40 20 20 20 20 20 50 4C   S ATM .G@     PL
0x0080: 45 41 53 45 20 54 41 4B 45 20 20 59 4F 55 52 20   EASE TAKE  YOUR 
0x0090: 43 41 52 44 1B 28 37 0F 49 40 20 20 20 20 20 20   CARD.(7.I@      
0x00A0: 20 5C 26 20 2D 28 23 58 3E 3D 20 5C 25 22 40 22    \& -(#X>= \%"@"
0x00B0: 20 41 22 20 0F 4A 40 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 57    A" .J@       0W
0x00C0: 5F 40 5B 3F 4A 58 20 2D 28 40 23 51 20 59 5F 22   _@[?JX -(@#Q Y_"
0x00D0: 20 0F 4B 40 20 20 30 3E 5F 40 22 3E 40 26 20 22    .K@  0>_@">@& "
0x00E0: 40 20 3E 5B 3D 20 20 2D 28 40 23 51 20 23 4D 47   @ >[=  -(@#Q #MG
0x00F0: 55 1B 28 32 1C 30 31 34 0C 1B 28 3E 0F 43 40 20   U.(2.014..(>.C@ 
0x0100: 20 20 45 53 50 2D 4C 49 4E 4B 2F 46 54 53 0F 45     ESP-LINK/FTS.E
0x0110: 40 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 41 54 4D 0F 47 40 20 4D   @       ATM.G@ M
0x0120: 41 52 4B 45 54 49 4E 47 20 4D 45 53 53 41 47 45   ARKETING MESSAGE
0x0130: 20 45 32 1C 30 31 35 0C 1C 30 31 38 0C 1C 30 32    E2.015..018..02
$
```

Here's the same data from `od -c`:

```
$ od -c file1 | sed 20q
0000000    3 034 034 034   1   1 034   0   0   1 016   2   0   1 034   0
0000020    0   2 016   2   0   1 034   0   0   3 016   2   0   3 034   0
0000040    0   4   $     034   0   0   5 016   0   0   2 034   0   0   6
0000060  016   0   0   2 034   0   1   1  \f 033   (   2 017   E   @    
0000100            Y   O   U   R       C   A   R   D       I   S       N
0000120    O   T           S   E   R   V   I   C   E   D 017   F   @    
0000140                                        B   Y           T   H   I
0000160    S       A   T   M     017   G   @                       P   L
0000200    E   A   S   E       T   A   K   E           Y   O   U   R    
0000220    C   A   R   D 033   (   7 017   I   @                        
0000240        \   &       -   (   #   X   >   =       \   %   "   @   "
0000260        A   "     017   J   @                               0   W
0000300    _   @   [   ?   J   X       -   (   @   #   Q       Y   _   "
0000320      017   K   @           0   >   _   @   "   >   @   &       "
0000340    @       >   [   =           -   (   @   #   Q       #   M   G
0000360    U 033   (   2 034   0   1   4  \f 033   (   > 017   C   @    
0000400            E   S   P   -   L   I   N   K   /   F   T   S 017   E
0000420    @                               A   T   M 017   G   @       M
0000440    A   R   K   E   T   I   N   G       M   E   S   S   A   G   E
0000460        E   2 034   0   1   5  \f 034   0   1   8  \f 034   0   2
$
```

And here's a character frequency analysis of the data:

```
  =   3:      1
  =  10:      1
  =  12:    648
  =  14:    883
  =  15:   3461
  =  27:   1384
  =  28:    722
  =  32:  15248
! =  33:    178
" =  34:   1236
# =  35:   1847
$ =  36:      2
% =  37:     44
& =  38:    945
' =  39:    197
( =  40:   2096
) =  41:   1434
* =  42:    695
+ =  43:     25
, =  44:    446
- =  45:   1431
. =  46:     92
/ =  47:     29
0 =  48:   2453
1 =  49:   1279
2 =  50:   1052
3 =  51:    758
4 =  52:    427
5 =  53:    565
6 =  54:    299
7 =  55:    862
8 =  56:    414
9 =  57:    423
: =  58:     78
; =  59:    330
< =  60:      3
= =  61:    313
> =  62:   1683
? =  63:     60
@ =  64:   3472
A =  65:   2268
B =  66:    791
C =  67:   2034
D =  68:   1480
E =  69:   2862
F =  70:    732
G =  71:    692
H =  72:    799
I =  73:   1202
J =  74:    360
K =  75:    358
L =  76:    963
M =  77:    823
N =  78:   1483
O =  79:   1726
P =  80:    588
Q =  81:    507
R =  82:   1411
S =  83:   1624
T =  84:   1905
U =  85:   1172
V =  86:    151
W =  87:    372
X =  88:   1063
Y =  89:    647
Z =  90:    758
[ =  91:   1026
\ =  92:    665
] =  93:    275
^ =  94:    397
_ =  95:   1179
a =  97:      1
c =  99:      1
d = 100:      1
m = 109:    240
o = 111:      2
p = 112:      2
q = 113:      4
r = 114:      2
s = 115:      2
t = 116:      4
u = 117:      1
w = 119:      1
y = 121:      1
z = 122:     15
```

The sum of the numbers in the last column is 80106, which agrees with `wc`.

As you can see, there is just one newline (code 10) and it appears at the very end of the file.  There are very few lower-case letters, a lot of upper-case letters, a moderate number of backslashes, but (what you can't see from the data shown so far is that) none of the backslashes are followed by a digit.  Note that there are no character codes outside the ASCII range (none with the high bit set), and the coverage of the ASCII range is not complete either.

I wrote a quick analysis program to see what characters follow a backslash:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            c = getchar();
            count[c]++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        if (count[i] != 0)
            printf("%3d = %5d\n", i, count[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run on the file, it produced:

```
 12 =     3
 14 =    58
 15 =     3
 27 =    25
 34 =    10
 35 =    51
 37 =    14
 38 =   126
 40 =     9
 44 =    51
 45 =    26
 47 =     2
 59 =    17
 62 =   118
 64 =    46
 65 =     2
 66 =     2
 67 =    17
 69 =     1
 71 =     4
 72 =     5
 74 =    15
 79 =     1
 81 =     9
 83 =     1
 85 =     5
 88 =    18
 90 =    12
 91 =     6
 95 =     8
```

The sum of the counts is 665, which agrees with the number of backslashes in the original character analysis.

The digits have codes 48..57; not one of the characters after a backslash is a digit.

This is why the various solutions shown fail — they never stood a chance because the data doesn't even begin to resemble what is described.

Comment: it seems sed solutions failed because of long line, is there tr solution for this?

Comment: @alwaystudent No, it has nothing to do with line length.  What Jonathan's detailed analysis found was that the pattern that you asked about, `\[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, _occurs nowhere in the file_.   That is why the `sed` solution did not break up the lines.

Comment: @John1024 : you are right , i get it, now,  so my pattern is:  FS [0-9][0-9][0-9]  , (FS: filed separator)    , how use that in your sed script

Comment: @alwaystudent: With Bash and BSD `sed`, you can use `sed -E $'s/(.)(\x1C[[:digit:]]{3})/\\1\\\n\\2/g' file1`.  The `$'…'` notation is [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).  The doubled backslashes represent a backslash seen by `sed`; the `\n` preceded by `\\` satisfies the `sed` manual which says: _A line can be split by substituting a newline character into it.  To specify a newline character in the replacement string, precede it with a backslash._  Check on what works with GNU `sed` (this was under the `s///` entry).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : its works now, with your analysis and adjustment!

Comment: @alwaystudent Since Jonathon's solution works, you should click on the checkmark next to his answer to mark it as solving your problem.

Comment: @John1024 : I did it

Comment: what is the *point* of this answer? it is *terrible*

Comment: @mikeserv — It has two purposes. (1) It shows that I was (unexpectedly) sent the actual data file, which then allowed me to show everyone else who was trying to answer what we were actually dealing with. (2) It gives an actual `sed` script that works directly on some Unix machines (those running BSD or Mac OS X) and that can readily be adapted to other machines (those with GNU `sed` on board), and which fixes the data as the OP wanted. It also points out one of the sources of confusion — the distinction between backslash and control-backslash.

Comment: the `sed` is *awful*, and the miles of answer that occur before it is completely unnecessary. there is an answer here that achieves all that you mentioned and more in only a couple of paragraphs - though it has a -1 overall rating. you should try to include more useful information in your answers per page in future.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
$ cat file
\001abd \002pqr \003xyz
$ sed -E 's/(.)(\\[[:digit:]]{3})/\1\n\2/g' file
\001abd 
\002pqr 
\003xyz
```

Using the same sed command but your other data example:

```
$ cat file2
CHANGE^\039^OE@ MORE^\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
$ sed -E 's/(.)(\\[[:digit:]]{3})/\1\n\2/g' file2
CHANGE^
\039^OE@ MORE^
\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^
\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
```

#### Update: splitting on FS-digit-digit-digit

The ASCII "file separator" (FS) character is hexadecimal `1C`.  Using GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.)(\x1c[[:digit:]]{3})/\1\n\2/g'
```

To demonstrate this, let's create a test file:

```
$ echo $'One\x1c123Two\x1c456Three\x1c7none' >newfile
```

Now, let's run `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.)(\x1c[[:digit:]]{3})/\1\n\2/g' newfile
One
123Two
456Three7none
```

The lines are successfully split.

#### Discussion

On my terminal, as shown above, the FS characters are invisible.  The do become visible when running less.  For example, running `less newfile` results in the display:

```
One^\123Two^\456Three^\7none
```

Here we can see that the FS character is displayed as `^\`.  This is consistent with the second example input shown in the question:

```
CHANGE^\039^OE@ MORE^\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
```

Comment: i suspect that the real data isn't text, and those `\039`, `\0E@` etc aren't literal characters but representations of control codes.  `\040` is probably space character.  `^L` is a form-feed.  `^[[00m` is part of some sort of ansi or vt100 code.  in fact, it looks a lot like a `script` log.

Comment: @John1024 it work for my example, but unfortunately failed  for real -long-data so i think this script fail for long line, is there a adjustment for huge data?

Comment: @alwaystudent: How long is the 'one line file'?  Kilobytes, Megabytes, bigger?  Which version of `sed` are you running (which o/s are you on — what's available on HP-UX is very different from what's available on Linux, BSD, Mac OS X).  Please add such information to the question.

Comment: @alwaystudent If you are using GNU sed, large data needs no adjustment.  As Jonathan Leffler asked, what OS and `sed` version are you using?  How big is your "huge data"?  Also, please do a hexdump, e.g. `od -c file | sed 10q`, so we can be sure what is actually in the file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   size of one line file is 80KB  and  GNU sed version 4.2.1 and OS is  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) and od -c file | sed 10q

Comment: 0000000   3 034 034 034   1   1 034   0   0   1 016   2   0   1 034   0\
0000020   0   2 016   2   0   1 034   0   0   3 016   2   0   3 034   0\
0000040   0   4   $     034   0   0   5 016   0   0   2 034   0   0   6\
0000060 016   0   0   2 034   0   1   1  \f 033   (   2 017   E   @\
0000100           Y   O   U   R       C   A   R   D       I   S       N\

Comment: 0000120   O   T           S   E   R   V   I   C   E   D 017   F   @\
0000140                                       B   Y           T   H   I\
0000160   S       A   T   M     017   G   @                       P   L\
0000200   E   A   S   E       T   A   K   E           Y   O   U   R\
0000220   C   A   R   D 033   (   7 017   I   @\

Comment: @alwaystudent: GNU `sed` will handle 80 KiB in a single line without problem (he says without formally checking, but with great confidence).  If the code here is not working, then we need to see the byte sequences that are actually in the file.  And please **pay attention** — add it to the question where you can format it; do not add it to a comment where it cannot be formatted!  You can edit your own question.

Comment: I tried to disentangle your 'od -c' output, but couldn't see anything that was reliably a backslash followed by three digits.  There are lots of control characters in the data.  When you *paste the data into the question*, indented by 4 spaces (select it, then use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it)…when you paste it, we'll be able to see better.  You should identify the byte offsets where you think the newlines should be generated.  At the moment, it is not clear to me what you've got as data, or why there are backslashes after the 16th character on many of the lines.

Comment: Also note that when you ask a question, or when people are leaving comments, it is helpful if you stick around to answer such issues.  People are expending effort to try and help you; the very least you can do is expend a little effort to help them help you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go from:

```
\001abc \002jkl \003xyz
```

...to...

```
\001abc
\002jkl
\003xyz
```

...then the most simple and performant solution is to do:

```
tr \  \\n <in >out
```

That, however, is not the same as splitting out your input on `\n`ewlines according to your `\[0-9][0-9][0-9]` pattern, which could be effected like:

```
sed 's/\\[0-9]\{3\}/&\n/g' <in >out
```

...and would result in...

```
\001
abc \002
jkl \003
xyz
```

...although I suppose you could mean you want to insert a `\n`ewline *before* each occurrence of `\[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, in which case you could do:

```
sed 's/\\[0-9]\{3\}/\n&/g' <in >out
```

...to get...

```
\001abc 
\002jkl
\003xyz
```

...with a trailing space on the end of each line.

But both of those might have problems dealing with very long input lines. If your entire input file is only the one line, then we can reliably do:

```
{   tr '\\' \\n | 
    sed -e:t \
        -e'$!N;/\n[0-9]\{3\}/!s/\n/\\/;tt' \
        -e's/\n/&\\/;P;D'
}   <infile >outfile
```

The above command chain will `tr`ansliterate *all* backslashes in input to `\n`ewline characters then pipe the results to `sed` which will recursively `t`est the head of each input line for three digits. `tr` won't have any issues dealing with long input lines at all, and, by the time it is through with it, its output should contain at least many `\n`ewline characters as you need. If a `\n`ewline character is *not* immediately followed by three digits then it is simply replaced with a backslash, else if it *is* then a backslash is inserted between the `\n`ewline character and the three digits.

The results for your second example are:

---

```
CHANGE^
\039^OE@ MORE^
\040^L^[[00m^OAC DEPOSIT TO WHICH ACCOUNT^N020^^
\055^L^[(1^[[00m^OAA PAYMENT FROM WHICH ACCOUNT^N020
```